# My bar charts overlap eachother. Need help to solve it

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, diagram

im making a code where I have an input field and a button on my screen. In the code below btnLeggTil (its norwegian) adds the number you wrote in the input field. It determines the height of the bars. My code is supposed to let the user add bars of whatever the height he/she prefers. As you can see I have put alot of my code inside a loop. The problem with the code is that the bars it makes, overlap eachother. I need to have a space between each bar, but don't know how. Thanks in advance! You can test out the code yourself and see (just remember to make a button and input field with names btnLeggTil and txtInn.

("høyde" means height) ("bredde" means width) ("verdier" means values) sorry its all norwegian

```
var verdier:Array = new Array();

btnLeggTil.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, leggtil);
function leggtil (evt:MouseEvent)
{
    verdier.push(txtInn.text);
    var totHøyde:int = 200; //total height on diagram
    var totBredde:int = 450; //total width on diagram
    var antall:int = verdier.length;

    var xv:int = 50; 
    var yb:int = 350;
    var bredde:int = (totBredde/antall) * 0.8;
    var mellom:int = (totBredde/antall) * 0.2;
    var maksHøyde:int = maksVerdi(verdier);

    function maksVerdi(arr:Array):Number //finds the biggest value in the array
    {
        //copies to not destroy the order in the original
        var arrKopi:Array = arr.slice();

        arrKopi.sort(Array.NUMERIC|Array.DESCENDING);
        return arrKopi[0];
    }

    for(var i:int = 0; i < verdier.length; i++)
    {
        graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000); 
        graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00); 
        graphics.drawRect(xv + (bredde+mellom)*i, yb, bredde, -verdier[i] * (totHøyde/maksHøyde));
        graphics.endFill();

        var txtTall = new TextField();
        txtTall.x = xv + (bredde+mellom)*i + 5;
        txtTall.y = yb - verdier[i] - 10;
        txtTall.type = "dynamic";
        txtTall.text = verdier[i];
        addChild(txtTall);
    }
}
```

Comment: You arent clearing graphics, so previous drawing will be always there on page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your for loop a bit,

```
graphics.clear();
graphics.lineStyle(2, 0x000000); 
graphics.beginFill(0x00ff00); 
for(var i:int = 0; i < verdier.length; i++)
{

    graphics.drawRect(xv + (bredde+mellom)*i, yb, bredde, -verdier[i] * (totHøyde/maksHøyde));


    var txtTall = new TextField();
    txtTall.x = xv + (bredde+mellom)*i + 5;
    txtTall.y = yb - verdier[i] - 10;
    txtTall.type = "dynamic";
    txtTall.text = verdier[i];
    addChild(txtTall);
}
graphics.endFill();
```